# How to open any built-in app through application

Tags: macos

my mac os application is running in full screen mode. 
On button click i'm opening finder window which allow me to open any another file or application but problem is that, when i open any another app, screen switches back to xCode and that application opens. Need to open selected app/file above same window.

**I have tried:**

```
**[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:path];**
```

passing application path to launchAppication method

How can i do this?????
Help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically because using `[NSView enterFullScreenMode:withOption:]` will set the app's `[NSWindow level]` to `kCGMaximumWindowLevel - 1`, so that all other app's windows will appear behind it.

This is kinda what you would expect from a fullscreen app, which implies system-modal behaviour.

I guess the only way of allowing another app to appear in front of the fullscreen app would be to lower the window level, however I have no idea what effect that would have.

Comment: No i'm not using [NSView enterFullScreenMode:withOption:] i'm using     [self.window setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];   and to open finder i'm using NSOpenPanel

Comment: @user316610 And what's the `[NSWindow level]` of your app?